# django many to many form is not showing model str

Tags: django

#### Models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    courses = models.ManyToManyField('Course', through='Membership')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')
    def __str___(self):
        return self.title

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

#### Form.py

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['name', 'email','courses']
    courses = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Course.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

#### Views.py

```
class CourseFormView(generic.CreateView):
    model = Course
    fields = ['title']

class PersonFormView(generic.CreateView):
    model = Person
    fields = '__all__'
    reverse_lazy('hello:cookie')
```

[preview here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KWLX.png)

Why the html that render show Object. How can I show the course title in that form

I try to show course title in user view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `PersonsFormView` specify template Name

```py
class PersonFormView(generic.CreateView):
    model = Person
    #fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'person_form.html'
    #reverse_lazy('hello:cookie')
    success_url = reverse_lazy('hello:cookie')
```

and Create template file name `person_form.html`

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <ul>
    {% for course in form.courses %}
      <li>
        <label for="{{ course.id_for_label }}">
          {{ course.choice_label }}
        </label>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

replace `choice_label`   to thier display  title or any thing you want